# MasterPage Access Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 master page in my web site.

1. MainMaster
2. SubMaster (Master Page:MainMaster)
3. Page (Master Page:SubMaster)

I have hidden fields on SubMasterPage. And i'm proccessing datas and setting hidden field value on SubMasterPage Init event. I want to get hiddenfield's value from Page.aspx 
I'm trying this on Page.aspx, getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error

```
 ((HiddenField)this.Master.FindControl("hiddenId")).Value
```

But when i have 1 master page this code works normally.

Have i a solution in this problem? Or should i try transfer datas via session/querystring e.t.c.?

Comment: You may have to recurse up the masters.  Potentially you might want something like this.Master.Master? Its not great code though. Also instead of casting if you did  " blah AS HiddenField" and did a null check before accessing the property it wouldnt brick.

Comment: and what I mean is adding a method like an extension method on control something with a signature like FindControlUp(This control, control startControl, string controlName) and then do the appropriate walking up the control hierarchy.

Comment: @Avinash send an e-mail me pls

Comment: Sure! Btw how are you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a property to your sub master page to return the value, and use this in the child page.

eg.

Sub Master Page

```
public string HiddenValue
{
   get
   {
      //return the value of your hidden field
      return HiddenID.Value;
   }
}
```

Child page:

```
//Method to get the hidden value from the master page, if the master page is a sub master page
private string GetHiddenValue()
{
   if (this.Master is SubMasterPage)
   {
      string value = (this.Master as SubMasterPage).HiddenValue;
      return value;
   }
   else
   {
      return string.Empty;
   }
}
```

if you want to go one step further you could add an extension method to the MasterPage class to call it easily from any page.

eg:

```
public static class MasterPageExtensions
{
    public static string GetHiddenFieldValue(this MasterPage master)
    {
        if (master is SubMasterPage)
            return (master as SubMasterPage).HiddenFieldValue;
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }
}

public class SubMasterPage : MasterPage
{
    private HiddenField _hiddenField;

    public string HiddenFieldValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _hiddenField.Value;
        }
    }
}

public class ChildPage : Page
{
    void TestMethod()
    {
        string hiddenValue = this.Master.GetHiddenFieldValue();
    }
}
```

this is particularly useful when for example you have a single modal popup message box on the master page, and you want to show it from any child page.

Comment: When i tried writing a method on submaster page to finding my hidden field it throws error. But now i tried public property for hiddenfield on submaster page, i get value normally :-o thank a lot  

public string pHidden { get { return hidMyHidden.Value; } }